# ifort - separate object and mod files into different folder

Tags: compilation, fortran, intel-fortran

I'm able to compile and output the object file ".o" into my "obj" folder.  But, I can't make the ".mod" into my "mod" folder.  The following is my current command:

```
ifort -c foo.f90 -o../obj/foo.o
```

Comment: Without wanting to sound rude: if i found, I won't ask here.

Comment: The ifort option is -module <path>

Answer (score 9):

Use the [`-module`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/525111) command line option to specify the directory for the output of the mod files that result from compiling Fortran modules.